# Migrate from Ubuntu 16.04.7 to 22.04.2 / 2 IP's / 2 NIC's same Subenet / Same Gateway

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, ethernet, ip-address, netplan

I need to migrate an application from an Ubuntu Server 16.04.7 to 22.04.2. The hosted service requires two IP addresses, one for each of the two NICs. The `default section` with the `nexthop` info from the `ip route` command output is missing on the new server, but can be seen in the `ip route` command output from the old server. I'm missing a puzzle piece here.

With `netplan` I can't get it configured correctly. Therefore my question how do I get that translated to `netplan`.

These are my config files from the old 16.04.7 server:

```
**/etc/network/interfaces**

iface enp4s0f0 inet static
        address 10.177.95.38
        netmask 255.255.255.128
        network 10.177.95.0
        broadcast 10.177.95.127
        dns-nameservers 10.244.8.240
        up ip route add 10.177.95.0/25 dev enp4s0f0 src 10.177.95.38 table t1
        up ip route add table t1 default via 10.177.95.1 dev enp4s0f0

iface enp4s0f2 inet static
        address 10.177.95.39
        netmask 255.255.255.128
        network 10.177.95.0
        broadcast 10.177.95.127
        dns-nameservers 10.244.8.240
        up ip route add 10.177.95.0/25 dev enp4s0f2 src 10.177.95.39 table t2
        up ip route add table t2 default via 10.177.95.1 dev enp4s0f2
```

```
**/etc/iproute2/rt_tables**
100 t1
101 t2
```

And this is the output from `ip route` command.

```
default
        nexthop via 10.177.95.1  dev enp4s0f0 weight 1
        nexthop via 10.177.95.1  dev enp4s0f2 weight 1
10.177.95.0/25 dev enp4s0f0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.177.95.38
10.177.95.0/25 dev enp4s0f2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.177.95.39
```

This is my current netplan config from 22.04.2 server.

```
**/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml**

network:
  ethernets:
    ens1f0:
      addresses:
      - 10.177.95.38/25

      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 10.177.95.1
        table: 1

      routing-policy:
      - from: 10.177.95.38
        table: 1
        priority: 1

      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 10.244.8.240
        search:
        - foo.bar

    ens1f1:
      addresses:
      - 10.177.95.39/25

      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 10.177.95.1
        table: 2

      routing-policy:
      - from: 10.177.95.39
        table: 2
        priority: 1

      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 10.244.8.240
        search:
        - foo.bar
  version: 2
```

And this is the output from `ip route` command.

```
10.177.95.0/25 dev ens1f0 proto kernel scope link src 10.177.95.38
10.177.95.0/25 dev ens1f1 proto kernel scope link src 10.177.95.39
```

Thanks in advance